# Sort table with child-rows

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I know this might be tricky, but I have been strived for a solution with no luck, so I have a table with expandable/collapsable row/child-rows:

```
Col1            Col2    Col3
Node A          A       A
  --A child 1   A1      A1
  --A child 2   Foo     Bar
Node B          Foo     Bar
  --B child 1   B1      B1
  --B child 2   Foo     Bar
```

So while all child-rows got expanded and I am sorting Col1, I am expecting to sort Node A and Node B, **NOT** sort all the child rows, i.e., if sort Col1, I should see this:

```
Col1            Col2    Col3
Node B          Foo     Bar
  --B child 1   B1      B1
  --B child 2   Foo     Bar
Node A          A       A
  --A child 1   A1      A1
  --A child 2   Foo     Bar
```

Not this....:

```
Col1            Col2    Col3
  --B child 1   B1      B1
  --B child 2   Foo     Bar
  --A child 1   A1      A1
  --A child 2   Foo     Bar
Node B          Foo     Bar
Node A          A       A
```

My code is located at: https://jsfiddle.net/wayneye/tyxykyf3/, I was using [jquery table sorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter), but don't restrict to use it as long as my requirement satisfied: **sort the parent rows, not child-rows**

Please kindly give me a hand, you can change my HTML structure/js, or using other libs, appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check [this link here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html), it states the following (for tablesorter 2.15.12+, and you are using 2.25.4):

> Parents of child rows now have a tablesorter-hasChildRow class name
>   added.

If you look at the example on that page, you will also note that there is a class for child rows `tablesorter-childRow`.

You simply need to add `tablesorter-hasChildRow` to your parent rows, and `tablesorter-childRow` to your child rows.

[Updated JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tyxykyf3/7/)

Comment: @WayneYe No problem at all, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS, you can just write a sort function on a collection of the rows. You'd also have to add an id to the parent rows of the form `id="A-parent"` for my particular solution:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcbq843o/2/

JS:

```
var sortTable = function (ascending) {
  var tableBody = document.querySelector('#tb > tbody');
  //Get the rows as a native js array.
  var rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr'));
    //Native js sort function.
    rows.sort(function(first,second){
    //The difference between char codes lets us sort alphabetically.
    //If they have the same code, they will be left in the same order.
    //This means that the children will still be in the same relative position.
    var posFirst = first.id.charCodeAt(0);
    var posSecond = second.id.charCodeAt(0);
    //Subtract, based on whether we want ascending or descending.
    return ascending ? posSecond - posFirst : posFirst - posSecond;
  });

  //Add the rows back to the table in our new order.
  for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        tableBody.appendChild(rows[i]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Since I've used tablesorter, I'd prefer to keep using it!